# Поиск по таблице в бд

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Есть таблица в которой ФИО разделено на три столбца "`first_name`", "`last_name`"  и "`middle_name`".

Как реализовать поиск по ФИО если он предоставлено одной строкой, пример: "Иванов Иван Иванович"?

Я пришёл только к такому варианту:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE 
(first_name || ' ' || last_name || ' ' || middle_name) LIKE '%Иванов Иван Иванович%' OR 
(last_name || ' ' || first_name || ' ' || middle_name) LIKE '%Иванов Иван Иванович%' OR 
(middle_name || ' ' || first_name || ' ' || last_name) LIKE '%Иванов Иван Иванович%';"
```

Comment: Превратить критерий в набор записей, а потом обычное реляционное деление. Ещё разумнее прикрутить полнотекст. Оба варианта могут использовать индексы.